# Using Parse Javascript SDK in express app with Parse-Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, parse-server

I have a node.js express app using the Parse Javascript SDK and Parse-Server.

I've set everything up according to the [guide](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Parse-Server-Guide) but the JS SDK is not working.

I'm getting `{error:unauthorized}`.  I can access my server with REST API just fine but not from within the app using the JS SDK.

I read that you have to specify `useMasterKey = true` for all operations with Parse-Server so:

```
var User = Parse.Object.extend('_User');
var query = new Parse.Query(User);
query.useMasterKey = true;

query.find().then( function(results) {
    console.log(results);
},
function(error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Should return the same data that this curl does (right?):

```
curl -X GET \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: myAppId" \
-H "X-Parse-Master-Key: myMasterKey" \
http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/_User
```

Alas, this is not the case.

Same error message when I try to run the default cloud code function:

```
 Parse.Cloud.run('hello').then( function(response) {
    console.log(response);
 },
 function(error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
 });
```

Any ideas that might help?  Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. I get the `{error:unauthorized}` when trying to access the url the Parse Server is located "baseURL/parse". Also, when using the javascript SDK within the express app setting up the Parse Server, the Cloud Code functions always return an error. Has anybody been able to get Parse Server and the Parse JS SDK running from an Express app?

Comment: I just posted my solution.  Thanks for posting yours.  I left out the `Parse.initialize` lines altogether (because the server does that) and I don't have to use the masterkey in my queries or cloud code.  Everything just works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was inexperience:

I am using [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser-json) and had the app set up to use that module's `raw`, `json`, `text`, and `urlencoded` middleware functions.

I only needed the `urlencoded` option.  I removed the others and the JS SDK started working fine.  Somehow, the other functions were interfering with the SDK.

Answer (score 4):

Got it!

What did it for me were these lines in my Express app

```
 var Parse = require('parse/node').Parse;
 Parse.initialize('app_id', 'js_key','master_key');
 Parse.serverURL = 'serverURL';
 Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
```

After these lines, any kind of call that requires Cloud Code usage or Parse usage were authorized